# Calculate value of wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> The wave equation is given as below: $$ u_{tt}−u_{xx}= 0$$
>
> $$ u(x, 0) = \begin{cases} 
>        1 - (x+3)^2 & (-4 < x < -2) \\
>       8 - 2(x-4)^2 & (2 < x < 6)  \\
>       0 & (x \leq -4, -2 \leq x \leq 2, x \geq 6)     \end{cases} \ u_t(x, 0) = 0 $$
>
> Find the value of $u(0,2)$, $u(0,3)$, $u(0,8)$

Since $-2 < 0 < 2$, the value should be $0$, but actually it's not. Why?

Comment: Why would you think it 0? It has nothing to do with the initial condition.

Comment: hmm actually I don't really understand this type of problem.

Comment: There are actually *three* questions here, looking for three answers. Some of those answers may well be 0. I assume that this is a homework question, so check in your notes for the "d'Alembert solution to the wave equation". There should be some easier examples next to it.